# Linux Shell in C: Execvp not finishing execution when wait is added to parent

Tags: c, linux

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "command.h"

int fd[10][2];
void closePipe(int fd_in,int fd_out);
void execute_commands(struct command mycommands[], int no_commands){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<no_commands-1;i++){
        pipe(fd[i]);
    }
    i=0;
    while(i<no_commands){
        if(i==0){
            if(no_commands==1){
                execute_command(mycommands[i].comm,mycommands[i].no_args,mycommands[i].args,-1,-2);
            }
            else{
                execute_command(mycommands[i].comm,mycommands[i].no_args,mycommands[i].args,-1,0);
            }
        }
        else if(i==no_commands-1){
            execute_command(mycommands[i].comm,mycommands[i].no_args,mycommands[i].args,no_commands-2,-1);
        }
        else{
            execute_command(mycommands[i].comm,mycommands[i].no_args,mycommands[i].args,i-1,i);
        }
        i++;
    }
    i=0;
    for(i=0;i<no_commands-1;i++){
        close(fd[i][0]);
        close(fd[i][1]);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<=no_commands;i++){
        wait(NULL);
    }

}

int execute_command(char *command, int argc, char *args[], int fd_in, int fd_out )
{
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if(pid==0){
        int out = dup(1);
        if(fd_in==-1){
            if(fd_out!=-2){
                close(1);
                dup(fd[fd_out][1]);
                close(fd[fd_out][0]);
            }
        }
        else if(fd_out==-1){
            closePipe(fd_in,fd_in);
            close(0);
            close(fd[fd_in][1]);
            dup(fd[fd_in][0]);
        }
        else{
            closePipe(fd_in,fd_in);
            close(fd[fd_in][1]);
            close(fd[fd_out][0]);
            close(0);
            dup(fd[fd_in][0]);
            close(1);
            dup(fd[fd_out][1]);

        }
        if(execvp(command,args)==-1){
            close(fd_out);
            dup2(out,1);
            printf("bash: %s: command not found...\n",command);
        }
        exit(0);
    }
    else{
        /*IF I INCLUDE WAIT(NULL) OR ANY WAIT FAMILY, EXECVP DOES NOT FINISH EXECUTING
          THIS CODE WORKS PERFECTLY NOW, BUT I NEED TO STOP THE PROGRAM IF THE USER ENTERS WRONG COMMAND WITH
          AN ERROR MESSAGE. SO I NEED TO INCLUDE WAIT HERE.
        */
    }
    return 0;
}

void closePipe(int fd_in,int fd_out){
    int i=-1;
    if(fd_in<fd_out)
        i=fd_in-1;
    else
        i = fd_out-1;

    int k=0;
    while(k<=i){
        close(fd[k][0]);close(fd[k][1]);
        k++;
    }
}
```

mycommands[] struct array contains the commands and its arguments to be executed. 
I did everything except one part. If one of the command is not valid i need to output an error message, the problem is when I put wait(NULL) or any wait command in the else part of execute_command (i.e the parent process) the program does not work for 2 commands or more commands, for some reason execvp does not stop executing.
It works when I don't add the wait(NULL). But since I need to stop the program if one of the command is invalid I need to use wait(&status) in the else part of execute_command function.

Someone please help. I am trying to solve this for the past 2-3 hours.

Comment: Proper indentation and spacing is *really* important to readability. I'd suggest putting that into a good editor like [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/) and have it indent it properly.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve -- a good question includes the *smallest* possible amount of code that can be used to reproduce the same problem. In this case, that means ideally only a main function with a fork(), execve() and a wait(), with arguments &c. hardcoded as much as possible while still being complete enough to run and demonstrate the problem.

Comment: I have made the code more readable.

Comment: this code block: `for(i=0;i<no_commands-1;i++){
        pipe(fd[i]);
    }` is not keeping the returned value(s) from the calls to `pipe()`, so there is no way for the code to know if a specific pipe was actually created or not.

Comment: what is the contents of the header file: `command.h`?  without that, we cannot debug the code

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a (single) blank line.  2) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: this code block: 1int k=0;
    while(k<=i) .... k++;` would be much better written as a `for()` loop

Comment: the function: `fork()` has three different return conditions: <0 when an error occurs, ==0 when in child process, >0 when in parent process. The posted code is failing to handle the error condition properly

Comment: in the posted code, the sub function: `execute_command()` is missing the prototype.  This results in the compiler making some assumptions about the return type and about the types of the parameters.  Most likely those assumptions are not correct.

Comment: the `wait()` is waiting for ANY child process to complete.  Since the posted code can be creating several child processes,  1) should probably keep the PID of each child process, so can call `waitpid()` 2) should follows a call to any `exec...()` function with `perror( "exec... failed" ); exit( EXIT_FAILURE );  to catch any such problems as the call to `exec...()` failing.

Comment: the use of appropriate comments that indicate WHAT the current code block is trying to accomplish would be VERY helpful.

Comment: this line: `if(execvp(command,args)==-1)` should be immediately followed by: `perror( '"execvp failed");  and that code block should have its' last statement be: `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`   Note: that call to `printf()` is very likely to not be correct, suggest removing that statement.  Also, the call to `exit(0);` after that code block should never be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing this block

```
for(int i=0;i<=no_commands;i++){
    wait(NULL);
}
```

And add `wait(NULL)` to the else part

```
else{
    /*IF I INCLUDE WAIT(NULL) OR ANY WAIT FAMILY, EXECVP DOES NOT FINISH EXECUTING
      THIS CODE WORKS PERFECTLY NOW, BUT I NEED TO STOP THE PROGRAM IF THE USER ENTERS WRONG COMMAND WITH
      AN ERROR MESSAGE. SO I NEED TO INCLUDE WAIT HERE.
    */
    wait(NULL);
}
```

Comment: @NihalAr tried your commands manually on terminal and they exit as expected?

Comment: @NihalAr are `args` set properly? (for each `args`, first pointer should point to the filename being executed and last pointer should be a null pointer.) If `execvp` hangs, there might be the reason.